# Why does adding a __new__ method to my class make it throw TypeError: object.__new__ takes no arguments?

Tags: python, class, magic-methods

I have a class that takes some constructor arguments like this:

```
class Works:
    def __init__(self, x):
        pass
```

This class works perfectly fine; I can call `Works(5)` no problem.

However, adding a `__new__` method to my class makes it stop working, even if the `__new__` method doesn't do anything except passing on the arguments it receives:

```
class Breaks:
    def __new__(cls, x):
        return super().__new__(cls, x)

    def __init__(self, x):
        pass
```

If I try to create an instance of this class, it throws an exception:

```
>>> Breaks(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "untitled.py", line 8, in __new__
    return super().__new__(cls, x)
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no arguments
```

Why does this `__new__` method that does absolutely nothing cause my class to stop working, and how can I fix it?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yep, you're right. Your google-fu is better than mine :)

Comment: check out: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5a4bbcd479ce86f68bbe12bc8c16e3447f32e13a/Objects/typeobject.c#L3538 which was linked to in the dupe